ContractB calls ContractA - Unable to transfer eth using msg.sender.call{value: val}("")
contract ContractA {
    constructor() payable {}

    function getTransfer() public {
        uint256 transferAmount = 0.1 ether;
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: transferAmount}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed");
    }
}

interface IContractA {
    function getTransfer() external;
}
contract ContractB {
    IContractA public contracta;

    constructor(address contractAddress) payable {
        contracta = IContractA(contractAddress);
    }

    function getTransfer() public payable {
        contracta.getTransfer();
    }
}

When calling ContractB.getTransfer() it always fails the msg.sender.call.  Is it possible to do this?

The issue was a lack of fallback()/receive() functions.  Hope this helps someone else down the line.
Working code looks like this:
contract ContractA {
    constructor() payable {}

    function getTransfer() public {
        uint256 transferAmount = 0.1 ether;
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: transferAmount}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed");
    }
}

interface IContractA {
    function getTransfer() external;
}

contract ContractB {
    IContractA public contracta;

    constructor(address contractAddress) payable {
        contracta = IContractA(contractAddress);
    }

    function getTransfer() public payable {
        contracta.getTransfer();
    }

    fallback() external payable {}

    receive() external payable {}
}

